# Coutinued output in file at each run

Tags: c++, filestream

How to avoid updating the file content at each run

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  ofstream file("file.txt");
  v2 = rand() % 100 + 1;
  file<< v2;
  file.close();
  return 0 ;
}
```

I am looking to add a new line at each run containing the new random value and conserving the old one wrote during the previous run .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the "append" mode when opening the file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <math>

int main() {
  std::ofstream file("file.txt", std::ios_base::app);
  v2 = rand() % 100 + 1;
  file << v2;
  file.close();
  return 0 ;
}
```

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode for details. Opening a file for output, without specifying the open mode, will by default truncate the file.

Comment: thanks @Andrew , How to display the output in only one row . for each run the output will be in same line as the output for the previous separated with a space . I am working on linux

Comment: Simply write the value followed by a space. If you don't write any newline characters, everything will appear on the same line: `file << v2 << " ";`

Comment: It works fine thanks @Andrew , do you have any Idea to have only  the  a limited results   in one line ?. For exemple I would like to display only 30 random numbers in the same line . then the result of the 31 run will be displayed in second line . taking into consideration that I want that each run generat just only one number . but the file should contains a limited result of all runs in one line .

Comment: You need to keep track of how many runs you've had. You can write this state to another file (and read it every time you run, to determine whether to insert a newline). Alternatively, open the file for both reading and writing, read in all the fields so far (to count them) and determine whether a newline is needed that way. A better solution, however, is to move your program logic into a function which can be run multiple times from a loop. Pass the loop counter as an argument and use it to determine whether to write a newline. If you need help with this, please post another question.

Answer (score 2):

By default opening a file for writing overwrites the existing file, if there is any. You need to specify an [open mode](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) that leaves the file as is. For example `ate` or `app` (which one to pick depends on your use-case).

[This `std::ofstream::open` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open) might help too.